# IP as webhook returns error 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, kik

I started developing a bot for kik based on the official kik documentation. When configuring, it returned an error C400 Bad Request`. I used the following entity:

```
{
    "webhook": "http://172.22.105.160:8080/kik/message",
    "features": {
        "manuallySendReadReceipts": false,
        "receiveReadReceipts": false,
        "receiveDeliveryReceipts": false,
        "receiveIsTyping": false
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, it did not fail when I replaced the webhook with `http://example.com:8080/kik/message`. Based on the different variations I tested, I believe it expects a string ending with a dot and at least two letters.

The API does not check whether the webhook really exists. The variant `172.22.105.160.com` was accepted, but as soon as it does match the regular expression `\.[A,z]{2,}`, it will be rejected.

Did anyone have similar experiences? I would like to use the IP as the webhook since it will be hosted on AWS. Do you have any suggestions to avoid this issue? Is it a bug in the API?

Comment: actually i didn't understand your problem can you clarify it more please ?

Comment: it seems that your host doesn't not exist, is this host connected with VPN ?